# Objective C, update table view after async operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous

I am running an async operation which loops through a json data file which should then update a table view.

Here's the code i'm using.

```
-(void) TopDealsRecieve:(NSString *)Devicetoken;
{

    currentcount = 0;

    allcontent = newArray;
    //Send device token and retireve TopDeals
    NSString *mainURL = @"http://myurl.com/api/";
    NSString *firstprefix = @"type=apicall&device=";
    NSString *deviceIDforURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", Devicetoken];
    NSString *stringToGoToEncoder = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", firstprefix, deviceIDforURL];
    NSData *plainData = [stringToGoToEncoder dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSString *returnURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", mainURL, base64String];
    NSURL *returncompletedURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:returnURL];

    //Retrieve Dictionary of Top Deals
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:returncompletedURL];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        //Get all output and store for segue
        NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
        currentcount++;
        numrows = [responseObject valueForKey:@"rows"];
        numrowscompare = [numrows integerValue];
        allLogos = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"logo"];
        allcontent = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"content"];
        allpostode = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"postcode"];
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)allcontent.count);
        allname = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"name"];
        alladdress = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"address"];
        alladdress2 = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"address2"];
        alllat = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"lat"];
        alllong = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"lng"];
        allstart = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"start"];
        allfinish = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"finish"];
        allstartnice = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"nicestart"];
        allfinishnice = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"nicefinish"];
        // hide the ticker

        [self.tableview reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        // 4
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Top Deals check internet connection!"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];

    [operation start];

}
```

When running the operation all the data comes in fine to the console, however the table view does not update with the correct data. It updates with the data in the all content array from before calling the function.

It seems that the data from the server isn't being passed to the table view quick enough. I somehow need to get the table view to reloadData AFTER the operation has been completed in some sort of queue.

```
[self.tableview reloadData];
```

Sorry if not too clear, any help appreciated.

Comment: What data is your `UItableViewDatasource` using ? Are you sure you're refreshing the correct `NSArray` ?

Comment: Also, what are all these 'Allxxxxx' variables ? Instance variables ? If so, you should better access them through properties, using a `__weak` pointer on self. Because if they are instance variables, your block is keeping a strong hidden reference to `self`, which you might not want...

Comment: data source is allcontent NSArray. The Allxxx are Global NSArrays

Answer (score 0):

If `allContent` is the `NSArray` your `UITableViewDatasource` uses, then you never update it in your completionBlockWithSuccess, so this isn't a problem of async update but rather a simple mistake : update `allContent` just before calling `reloadData`.

(One additionnal remark : using 'Global' arrays is bad!)

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by update allcontent? Isn't this done by allcontent = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"content"]; ?

Comment: Ok, sorry I missed that line. Where do you declare `allcontent` ? it should be a property of `self`.

Comment: At the top using 
NSArray *allcontent;

Comment: What do you mean "At the top", I cannot read YOUR code... in the `@interface`, as an instance variable? If not, try moving it there, and see if this solves your update problem.